# Grouping data by ID or seed

Tags: r

I have 100 patient's data (1 total file with rbind) with 2 columns (time,var1). 
I need to **group the data** (100 groups) in order to be able to plot the 100 patient's data.

I added a column `patientID` at the end to the whole data, but should be grouped in order to generate the 100 plots for each patient. Since I need the data together I dont want to split the total data.

I tried this and it didn't work:

```
Data1$ID <- 1  # third column now has the ID
total <- rbind(Data1,Data2,....)
total <- grouped.data(xdata = xdata, ydatalog = ydatalog, seed = total$ID)
plot(total)
```

As an example, this data from R works properly:

```
str(Loblolly)
Classes ‘nfnGroupedData’, ‘nfGroupedData’, ‘groupedData’ and 'data.frame':      84 obs. of  3 variables:
```

plot(Loblolly) # one plot for each patient since data is grouped

Comment: Do you want one plot showing all groups or multiple plots?

Comment: Multiple plots. However, I need to analyze the whole data with nmle (so should be grouped by patiend ID). For instance:                                                                                             fm1 <- nlme(height ~ Asym+(5*R0-Asym)*exp(-exp(lrc)*age),
data = Loblolly,
fixed = Asym + R0 + lrc ~ 1,
random = Asym ~ 1,
start = c(Asym = 103, R0 = -8.5, lrc = -3.3))

Comment: Solution:                                                                                                                                                                                                                   total.new <-  # create a new copy object
 groupedData( ydatalog ~ xdata | ID,
  data = as.data.frame( total ),....

Comment: You can answer your own question and then mark it correct!

Answer (score 1):

Solution: total.new <- # create a new copy object groupedData( ydatalog ~ xdata | ID, data = as.data.frame( total ),.